# Calling a Same web api with different api parameter value inside a loop

Tags: javascript, promise, xmlhttprequest

I have a function to fetch data from a web api and load it in the UI.
I am using angular js with xmlhttprequest to fetch data.
My function is like below.

```
     var testMethod = (resolve,reject)=>{
        $scope.responseData = [];
        var startCount =0;
        var isDataAvaialble = true;
        do {
          var url = "ur/api/search?start=" +startCount;
          $http({
          method : 'GET',
          url:url,
         }).then function successCallback(response){
         $scope.data= response.Data;
      for (var i =0 ; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
    {

// do something
    if(condition)
    {
    $scope.resonseData.push($scope.data[i]);
    isDataAvailable = true;
    }
    else
    {
    isDataAvailable =false;
    break;
    }
    }
});
    startCount ++;
    }while(isDataAvailable)
resolve($scope.response);
    };
```

But since I am using Promise inside the loop the loop is getting executed before the promise.
Instead if I use synchronous xmlhttprequest loop is working.

ie instead of

```
 var url = "ur/api/search?start=" +startCount;
              $http({
              method : 'GET',
              url:url,
             }).then function successCallback(response){
```

if I use

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, false);
    xhr.send(null);
$scope.data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

everything works. But I don't need to use synchronous here.

I need to get this done asynchronously. I need to get the $scope.responseData in other function

Comment: Welcome to SO Eddy, your code format could be better and your final sentence is cut off.

Try to improve the quality of your question for better results.

Comment: @Terrance00 Will take care of this next time. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: You can edit it bro!

Comment: Assuming I got right (code is almost illegible), you can use several approaches to achieve what you want. On the top of my head: async/await with a for-of loop or a function calling itself (recursive) until no more data is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$scope.responseData = [];

function testMethod(startCount = 0) {
    const url = `url/api/search?start=${startCount}`;

    return $http({ method : 'GET', url })
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.Data;

            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if(!condition) { return; }

                $scope.responseData.push(data[i]);
            }

            return testMethod(startCount + 1);
        });
}

testMethod();
```

Comment: This idea of using the recursion really helped.